# Validate jquery form how to not allow spaces in Full Name

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $("#contact_form");
    var FName = $("#fname"); //Creates Variables from forms 
    var FNameInfo = $("#fnameInfo");
    var Tele = $("#tele"); 
    var TeleInfo = $("#teleInfo"); 
    var Address = $("#address");
    var AddressInfo = $("#addInfo"); 
    var Email = $("#email");
    var EmailInfo = $("#EmailInfo"); 
    var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/; //ragex code 

    FName.blur(validateFName);  //blur is a method which attaches a functiom to run when an event occurs
    Email.blur(validateEmail); 
    Tele.blur(validateTele);
    Address.blur(validateAddress);

    form.submit(function(){
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { //Code used for blank space Validation 
            return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
        }, "No space please and don't leave it empty"); 

        $("contact_form").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    noSpace: true
                }
            }
        });

        if (validateFName() & validateTele() & validateEmail() & validateAddress()) { //If it passes all of these then return true 
            return true;    
        } else {
            return false;        
        }
    }); 

    function validateFName() {   //Creates function for Name Validation+
        if (FName.val().length < 5) {        //If name is length is less than 5 
            FName.addClass("error");  //Display error 
            FNameInfo.text("Please Enter Correct Name"); //Changes span name 
            FNameInfo.addClass("error");  //Same error 
            FNameInfo.removeClass("Valid");                  
            return false; 
        } 
        else  { 
            FName.removeClass("error");   //remove error class 
            FNameInfo.addClass("Valid") 
            FNameInfo.text("Thanks Buddy" );  //When user enters correct code this text will appear 
            FNameInfo.removeClass("error"); 
            return true; 
        }
    }
```

```html
<div> 
    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" /> 
    <span id="fnameInfo">Whats your full name?</span>
</div>
```

How do I get the validation to work for Full Name when user enters blank spaces? I have the code above but it doesn't seem to do anything. Would I need to change the function parameters?

Comment: Can you try `return (value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != "")?true:false`

Comment: including the ?true:false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"contact_form"` needs an `#` for id or `.` for class.

and the `name` for full name is `fname`.

so:-

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
    rules: {
       fname: {
         noSpace: true
       }
    }
});
```

should work.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9r98chp4/)

Comment: Thanks it does somehow work but this is only when I press space about 4 times anything over that it acts like its a valid input.